# Capturar formulário - Maneira mais correta

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Antigamente eu chamava um formulário especifico por ID de criação no corpo do documento:

```
document.forms[0]
```

Só depois fui entender pra que serve o atributo `NAME` nestes casos, mas fiquei na dúvida, por exemplo, tenho mais de um formulário na página, podendo ser um login ou cadastro e outro pesquisa, assim atribuo o nome correspondente pra cada um, sendo que quero usar o formulário de login pra validar por Javascript:

```
<form name="login">
<input type="text" value="" name="user" required />
<input type="password" value="" name="user" required />
<input type="button" onclick="validateLogin()" />
</form>
```

Só que eu nem sei qual a maneira correta de fazer isso, ambas funcionam no Firefox, Chrome e Opera:

1°:

```
document.forms['login']
```

2°:

```
document.forms.login
```

Então eu costumo fazer assim:

```
var form = document.forms['login'] || document.forms.login
```

E eu nem sei se isso funciona mesmo, mas faço por precaução pro caso de algum navegador não funcionar.

Então, qual seria a melhor ou maneira mais correta, pra funcionar em qualquer navegador de qualquer plataforma?

Answer (score 1):

Acho que não existe *maneira mais correta*, existe *maneira mais eficiente e prática*. Se você quer apenas submeter um formulário, você pode omitir o nome do formulário e enviar ele através do `this` no `onsubmit`, que torna o processo mais simples.

Por exemplo:

```js
function valida(i){

   if(!i.nome.value){
      alert("Informe o nome");
      return false;
   }

   if(!i.email.value){
      alert("Informe o email");
      return false;
   }
   
}
```

```html
<form action="destino.php" method="post" onsubmit="return valida(this)">
      <h2>Cadastro</h2>
      <input type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Nome" />
      <br>
      <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
    <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

> O parâmetro `i` da função `valida(i)` já é o formulário. Então só basta
>   você pegar os valores dos `inputs` (`i.nome.value`, `i.email.value` etc.).

Se você tiver outro formulário, é a mesma coisa. O `this` enviará os valores do formulário submetido. Desta forma você não se preocupa em saber "qual formulário capturar", porque o `this` já faz isso pra você.

Answer (score 0):

Ambos funcionam, ambos estão corretos (o modo de usar) e ambos retornam `HTMLCollection`.

Esse valor retorno é uma interface semelhante à um *array*, podendo utilizar `collection[0]` ou `collection.getItem(0)` e a um `object`, podendo utilizar `collection.form_name`.

A vantagem de utilizar o nome do formulário é que você não vai ter que se preocupar com formulário dinâmico, pois o índice desses, porém variar bastante.

Você também pode utilizar da seguinte forma (todas elas são capturam o mesmo valor).

```
const form1 = document.querySelector("form")
const form2 = document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0]
const form3 = document.forms[0]
const form4 = document.forms.login
```

**Exemplo:**

```js
const form1 = document.querySelector("form")
const form2 = document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0]
const form3 = document.forms[0]
const form4 = document.forms.login

console.log( form1 == form2 && form3 == form4 );

console.log( form1.elements.user );
console.log( form2.elements.user );
console.log( form3.elements.user );
console.log( form4.elements.user );
```

```html
<form name="login">
  <input type="text" name="user" value="Your user" />
  <input type="password" name="pass" value="Your pass" />
</form>
```

Comment: Vale lembrar também `document.querySelectorAll("form")[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

Bom eu particulamente prefiro usar Jquery por ser mais "facil" e mais "limpo visualmente" mas  como  vc está utilizando javascript puro aqui vai

```
<form name="login">
    <input type="text" value="" name="user" required />
    <input type="password" value="" name="senha" required />
    <input type="button" onclick="validateLogin()" />
</form>

<script>
    var form = document.getElementsByName("login");
    var campoUsuario = form.getElementsByName("user");
    var senha = form.getElementsByName("senha");
</script>
```

Existem outras formas de se obter o elemento
por ID, Class, Tipó

```
document.getElementById("algumid");
document.getElementsByClassName("algumaclass");
document.getElementsByTagName("div");
```